# Removing spaces, comma, decimals and euro symbol in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, formatting, hexadecimal

I've googled around and tried a lot of things but they seem to have no effect.

I have column that has values in this format:
897,00 €

I need to format it so that it does NOT have spaces or the euro symbol.

I try to format the cells with format cell, number, currency, no effect.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global Search & Replace will do the job since you only have a small number of items to get rid of.  I.e. replace all '€', ' ', and optionally '.', (if you want the thousands separator removed) with `''`.

You could also use a `SUBSTITUTE` formula.  With your example in A2, try this:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "€", ""), ".", ""))
```

Comment: I think the OP needs the `","` symbol in the text. Your solution removes that as well.... ?

Comment: hmmm, i'm certain the original post had commas and decimals in the list of undesired elements.  Edited.

Comment: Just saw [that](https://superuser.com/posts/1298382/revisions). You were right